# How do I print file for a specific parent/child using Get-ChildItem?

Tags: powershell, powershell-6.0

I'm able to recursively search a directory using Get-ChildItem -Recurse. But not getting output as expected. Tried -Depth also. But no luck.

Folder structure is like below:

**C:\Users\Documents\Azure\repo\Templates\directory***

**directory1-uat --> childdir1 --> childdir2 --> a.parameters.json**

**directory2-dev --> childdir1 --> childdir2 --> b.parameters.json**

**directory3-nonprod --> childdir1 --> childdir2 --> c.parameters.json**

**directory4-test --> childdir1 --> childdir2 --> d.parameters.json**

**directory5-uat --> childdir1 --> childdir2 --> e.parameters.json**

I've tried the following:

```
    $repo = 'C:\Users\Documents\Azure'
    $subDirs = Get-ChildItem -Path "$repo\Templates\*\" -Depth 0 -Directory | Where-Object fullname -notlike "*_Templates*"
    $subDirs
    ForEach ($subDir in $subDirs) {
        $subDir
        $envTag = $subDir.Name.split('-')[1]
        $envTag
        $subParamFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $subDir.PSParentPath -Recurse -File -Include "*parameters.json"
        $subParamFiles
    }
```

Output is:

```
    d-----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                directory1-uat
    uat
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                a.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                b.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                c.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                d.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                e.parameters.json
    d-----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                directory2-dev
    dev
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                a.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                b.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                c.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                d.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                e.parameters.json
    d-----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                directory3-nonprod
    nonprod
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                a.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                b.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                c.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                d.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                e.parameters.json
    d-----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                directory4-test
    test
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                a.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                b.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                c.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                d.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                e.parameters.json
    d-----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                directory5-uat
    uat
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                a.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                b.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                c.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                d.parameters.json
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                e.parameters.json
```

Expected Output:

```
    d-----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                directory1-uat
    uat
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                a.parameters.json
    d-----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                directory2-dev
    dev
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                b.parameters.json
    d-----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                directory3-nonprod
    nonprod
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                c.parameters.json
    d-----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                directory4-test
    test
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                d.parameters.json
    d-----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                directory5-uat
    uat
    -a----         02-Jan-20  8:48 PM                e.parameters.json
```

Comment: i think your problem is this `$subDir.PSParentPath`. i suspect that you are getting the _parent_ path ... and then it gets all the json files in the whole tree. what happens if you just use the actual path instead of the _parent_ path?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey  I have multiple directories : C:\Users\Documents\Azure\repo\Templates\directory*

Comment: you are printing the `$subDir` - in the 1st case that is `directory1-uat`. then you are getting the file list _of the parent directory of `$subDir`_. you want the files in `$subDir`, not in the entire parent tree. try replacing `$subDir.PSParentPath` with just `$subDir`.

Comment: also, you likely ought to look into using a custom object instead of manually building lines of text.

Comment: you are quite welcome! glad to help a little bit ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Would you consider adding this as an answer please so the OP can accept it? Otherwise it will be yet another question "unanswered" and that will make it harder for others to find if they have a similar question.

Comment: @Theo I can confirm the issue is resolved and this can be considered as answer.

Comment: @Theo - done! thank you for the heads up on posting it as an answer. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

you are printing the `$subDir` - in the 1st case that is `directory1-uat`. then you are getting the file list of the parent directory of `$subDir`. you want the files in *`$subDir`*, not in the entire parent tree. [*grin*]

try replacing `$subDir.PSParentPath` with just `$subDir`. this line ...

```
$subParamFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $subDir.PSParentPath -Recurse -File -Include "*parameters.json"
```

... would become this ...

```
$subParamFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $subDir -Recurse -File -Include "*parameters.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give the current path instead of parent path:

```
$subDirs = dir "C:\Users\Documents\Azure\Templates\*\" -Directory | ? {$_.fullname -notlike "*_Templates*"}
    $subDirs
    $subDirs | % {
        $_
        $_.Name.split('-')[1]
        dir $_ -Recurse -File -Filter "*parameters.json"
    }
```